# No output when trying to print

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python code in which I input a number, which should be a multiple of 3, and calculate the sum of each digit's power of 3, 
ig: input'12' => multiple of 3
should return 1^3 +2^3 = 9
I tried this script and didn't get anything when I run it, what's the problem

```
number= input('give a number: ')
TT=list(number)  
if int(number)==0:
    print('wrong number')
elif int(number)%3:
    for x in (range(len(TT))-1):
        aggregate=sum(int(TT[x])**3)
        print(f'the aggregate of {number} is {aggregate}')
```

Comment: 12 modulo 3 is 0, so neither of the branches is taken.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

None of the conditions are true, so no value ever gets displayed. If you input 12, then 12 % 3 equals 0 (False).

Take a look at the [python truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html)

You should update this line:

```
elif int(number)%3 == 0:
```

Now, the whole code needs a revision to get the result that you want. Let me make some changes:

```
number= input('give a number: ')
aggregate = 0
if int(number)==0:
    print('wrong number')
elif int(number) % 3 == 0:
    for x in number:
        aggregate += int(x) ** 3
print(f'the aggregate of {number} is {aggregate}')
```

Comment: `now says```sum(int(TT[x])**3)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable```

Comment: Yes, because the parameters passed to `sum` built-in method should be an iterable, not an integer.

Comment: And by the way, you should update this statement too: `for x in range(len(TT)-1):`

Comment: apparently x needs some type of conversion

Comment: No, not at all, that's not the issue, my friend. The whole code needs a revision. Let me fix that for you in my answer

Comment: I've just update the answer with the code fixed